# Help me to place two fields in a row in shipping methods edit form

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, forms, design

In our application 5 different product categories are available. I have created the form to mention the local and export shipping cost for each product type. I want to reorder the few fields display in tabular form. I have attached snapshots.

This is how currently displaying - https://i.stack.imgur.com/57U2k.jpg

Expected output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8NIX.jpg

[image: This is how currently displaying]
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1):

You need a new fieldset renderer, there is not one for what you want to do.  I suggest you go look at how Paypal does it as its a very good example. This is in the system.xml:

```
                <frontend_class>complex</frontend_class>
                <frontend_model>paypal/adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_group</frontend_model>
```

Then there is a class (under Block not Model) for this Fieldset where you will see html for rendering.